# Sort an Array Mixed With Integers and Strings - Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have an array that must be sorted with low number to high number and then alphabetical order. Must use Array#sort_by

```
 i_want_dogs = ["I", "want", 5, "dogs", "but", "only", "have", 3]
```

I want it to output:

```
 => [3,5,"I","but","dogs","have","only","want"]
```

I tried:

```
 i_want_dogs.sort_by {|x,y| x <=> y }
```

I know that is obviously wrong, but I can't figure it out with the integers and the strings combined.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by)?

Comment: Dumb question but do you need them in strings AND ints? :D

Comment: I did, but still cannot figure it out. I was thinking maybe I had to convert the integers to chr then everything to a number and sort it like that inside the block, or something like that, but I cannot get the syntax right.

Comment: @limelights - yeah, I need it to output exactly as shown above

Comment: Its interesting that the capital I is before the other words. `i_want_dogs.sort_by { |x, y| y.to_i <=> x.to_i }` should get you pretty close, but the "I" is at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the result:

```
i_want_dogs.sort_by {|x| x.to_s }
```

**UPDATE:**

Thanks @vacawama who points out that it will sort numbers alphabetically. If you need to sort number by it's value, other answers will be something you need to try.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Others kept using different methods, but it was required for me to use sort_by. Thank you +1

Comment: +1 Very clever solution! We can also add `downcase` should it be case-insensitive, e.g. `x.to_s.downcase`

Comment: @vacawama - it sorted them correctly on the test I did, but I didn't do numerous tests.

Comment: This won't sort your numbers correctly, if you care about that.  Numbers are sorted "alphabetically" instead of numerically. eg. [3, 32, 355, 4, 500] is sorted "alphabetically".

Comment: @vacawama You are correct. Looks it's kind of a small ruby exercise to try sort_by for this test case. If it really needs numbers sorted,your answer and others will be something he can try.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) method with a block that defines a comparator that does what you want. I wrote a simple one that compares values when the classes are the same and class names when they are different.

```
def comparator(x, y)
  if x.class == y.class
    return x <=> y
  else
    return x.class.to_s <=> y.class.to_s
  end
end
```

Use it like this:

```
i_want_dogs.sort { |x, y| comparator(x, y) }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `partition` to separate numbers from strings, sort each separately and join the final result, e.g.

```
i_want_dogs.partition { |i| i.is_a?(Fixnum) }.map(&:sort).flatten
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to convert the elements in the array to a string. Try this

```
i_want_dogs.sort_by(&:to_s)
```

This will return

```
[3,5,"I", "but", "dogs", "have", "only" "want"]
```